# How to know if the email is really sent?

Tags: java, android, email, testing

In my app, the user can decide to send an email to a friend just pressing a button "send mail". After that, my applications send the email. Here is the problem: the email cannot be sent automatically... for example, if the user has more email clients installed, the operating system will ask him which client use for sending email... And, most important, the user can decide to change idea and no more send the email...

So, the question: How to count the amount of sent emails? It is NOT correct to count the number of clicks of the button: I need to test if the email has been REALLY sent...

But... How?

Comment: Why do you need to know?  Are you paying users to spam their friends?

Comment: Paying? No. And however, a lot of social portals (linkedin, fb, etc.) let people send email to invite their friends to join. Is this spam? If yes, you should think about closing all of them...

Comment: I didn't question your helping users send emails, I questioned why you needed to know that the email had actually been sent, vs the user changing their mind and abandoning it unsent.  That need implies (though does not prove) that you are somehow rewarding users for sending emails and worried they might accept the reward without actually sending them.

Comment: Because I like to tell the user: "Among the 10 person you invited, 7 accepted your invitation, 3 didn't".

Comment: That doesn't imply a reward.  It could just be a measure of the success of the feature, and whether it warrants real estate or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seen that it's not possible using embedded email system, but seen that it's necessary keep count, I suggest using [this class](http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/166/) that send the email without promting.

For the first mail sent, user must input account username and password (be careful, read CommonsWare comment...), that can be stored encrypted with [this class](http://www.tutorials-android.com/learn/How_to_encrypt_and_decrypt_strings.rhtml) in the private structure [SharedPreferences](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/63.html).

So, due to the fact that the mail is sent programmatically, if the statement of the mail-sending doesn't throw any exception, we can consider the mail as sent...

Answer (score 1):

> How to count the amount of sent emails?

You don't. That is up to the user. Design your app such that you do not care if the user sends the email or not.

If the nature of your application is such that you absolutely have to know whether the email is sent, embed email sending straight into your application. There is a JavaMail port for Android floating around somewhere, IIRC. This may require you to get the user's email account and password, which they will not want to give you. Hence, I recommend that you design your app such that you do not care if the user sends the email or not.